# Executing bash in RMarkdown on Windows (Git-Bash)

Tags: r, windows, bash, rstudio, knitr

I want to execute bash statements in an RStudio .rmd file as follows.

````
```{bash}
ls 
```
````

At first RStudio would just hang showing the red button beside the code chunk. I figured out that the OpenSSH version of bash was opening a shell window, so by adjusting the windows system path, I got the `...\Git\bin\bash.exe` version to execute.

Then I got the following error in red:

```
bash: C:\Users\{me}\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpmEF1jM\chunk-code3cb46c6027b3.: No such file or directory
```

This happens with each of the only four engines (sh, bash, perl and python) that appear to be executable on the Rmarkdown page (showing a little green triangle to the right of the chunk).  This is less than the language examples described on [this page](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_knitr_engines.html) for Python, SQL, Bash, Rcpp, Stan, JavaScript and CSS and much less than the 38 contained in the `knitr::knit_engines` object.

Searching StackOverflow, I came across [this short example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45857934/executing-perl-6-code-in-rmarkdown/45864801#45864801) showing how to write your own language engine. So I modified it to access the Git-Bash shell, and registered the function as follows:

```
eng_gitbash <- function( options ) { ... } 
knitr::knit_engines$set( gitbash = eng_gitbash )
```

But then when I executed the chunk, `{r, engine='gitbash'}`, I got this error.

```
'"C:\Users\{me}\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpmEF1jM\chunk-code3cb476f93db0."' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I have read though a lot of Yihui Xie's excellent documentation, but I can't seem to find how to test the `eng_gitbash` function that I wrote.  If someone could show me how the "options$engine can be directly used in command line to execute the code", I might be able to get my own version working.

Also as a general question, can someone point me to a description of the environmental requirements for a language engine 1)to be recognizable as executable by RStudio and 2)to be executed properly using Windows temp files.

Thanks, Sue

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get my knitr language engine function to work and execute it "directly".  It's pretty simple:

```
eng_gitbash <- function( options ) {

# create a temporary file
  f <- basename( tempfile( "gitbash", '.', paste('.', "sh", sep = '' ) ) )
  on.exit( unlink(f) )    # cleanup temp file on function exit
  writeLines( options$code, f )
  out <- ''

# if eval != FALSE compile/run the code, preserving output
  if (options$eval) {
    out <- system2( "gitbash.cmd", f )
  }

# spit back stuff to the user
  engine_output( options, options$code, out )
  }

knitr::knit_engines$set( gitbash = eng_gitbash )
```

And it sort of works as a type of language chunk in an Rmarkdown file.  But as you can see from the screen capture below:

1. It executes by clicking on the little green triangle.  But what is the [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWEiM.png) output?
2. It executes with CTRL-SHIFT_ENTER.  But there is no little green triangle.
3. It doesn't execute and their is not little green triangle.

   *[ Screen capture of 3 chunks listed above ][1] (Alas, I'm not allowed to post images or more than two links until I have 10 reputation points)*

I can live with those issues. Although, when I tried it in the new beta version of RStudio, executing all three chunks with CTRL_ENTER worked fine. But then when I went to Knit the entire file, I got the two errors shown in the next screen capture below.

4. This error is caused by the execution of the `eng_gitbash` function directly in the first chunk.
5. The `eng_gitbash` function doesn't seem to be registered, even though I sourced an R-Script before knitting the file, and it worked when executing the individual chunks.

   *[ Screen capture of 2 errors listed above ][2] (Alas, I'm not allowed to post images or more than two links until I have 10 reputation points)*

How is the setup for knitting the whole page different than for individual chunks?

Comment: SInce I can't upload images, here are the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

```
processing file: eng_gitbash.Rmd
  |............
  ordinary text without R code

  |......................
label: unnamed-chunk-l
Quitting from lines 4-8 (eng_gitbash.Rmd)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : attempt to apply non-function  Calls:
         <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval

Line 4 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : attempt to apply non-function Calls:
         <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval


output file: eng_gitbash. knit.md

Output created: eng_gitbash.html
Warning messages:
1: In get_engi ne(optionsSengi ne) :
  Unknown language engine 'gitbash' (must be registered via knit_engines$set())

2: In get_engi ne(optionsSengi ne) :
  Unknown language engine 'gitbash' (must be registered via knit_engines$set())
```